# iOS 13 UINavigationBar does not automatically calculate size when UINavigationItem changes

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, ios13

There is a problem when you try changing `UINavigationItem` (in my case it is setting `searchViewController`) after the view was loaded: `UINavigationBar` does not change it's size to fit the new content. Strangely this bug is only noticed in iOS 13, everything was fine on older versions.
I have made a minimum reproducible example here https://gist.github.com/sam-moshenko/2e0310fe6e6dddace5f464e13ae3f972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is also visible in the example https://gist.github.com/sam-moshenko/2e0310fe6e6dddace5f464e13ae3f972
But it is commented out in line 8.

Solution is to manually update the `UINavigationBar`'s size by calling `sizeToFit`.